# 3d rendering error whilst looking backwards

Tags: python, 3d, python-turtle

I made a 3d voxel rendering engine in python (turtle) a few days ago. Everything seems to be going smoothly, until you turn around 360∘ while in front of an object. The object will appear mirrored on the y axis. I came up with a fix for it via setting your y rotation, but that fix only works from one viewing angle. There are no console errors whatsoever, so I cannot pinpoint the location of the rendering error. I wish I had more info to aid in locating the issue.

```
from turtle import*
from time import*
from math import*
wn=Screen()
speed(0)
ht()
pu()
wn.tracer(0,0)
fov=200
xoff=0
yoff=0
zoff=0
camx=0
camy=0
camz=-105
xrot=0
yrot=0
zrot=0
jvel=0
onground=False
def goto3d(x,y,z):
  rotxx=x
  rotxy=y*cos(xrot)-z*sin(xrot)
  rotxz=y*sin(xrot)+z*cos(xrot)
  rotyx=rotxx*cos(yrot)+rotxz*sin(yrot)
  rotyy=rotxy
  rotyz=rotxz*cos(yrot)-rotxx*sin(yrot)
  rotzx=rotyx*cos(zrot)-rotyy*sin(zrot)
  rotzy=rotyx*sin(zrot)+rotyy*cos(zrot)
  rotzz=rotyz
  transx=rotzx-xoff
  transy=rotzy-yoff
  transz=rotzz-zoff
  newx=fov*transx/transz
  newy=fov*transy/transz
  if newx<=-200 or newy<=-200 or newx>=200 or newy>=200:
    pencolor('black')
  else:
    goto(newx,newy)
def cube(x,y,z):
  z-=100
  pu()
  goto3d((-1+x)-camx,(-1+y)-camy,(-1+z)-camz)
  pd()
  goto3d((-1+x)-camx,(1+y)-camy,(-1+z)-camz)
  goto3d((1+x)-camx,(1+y)-camy,(-1+z)-camz)
  goto3d((1+x)-camx,(-1+y)-camy,(-1+z)-camz)
  goto3d((-1+x)-camx,(-1+y)-camy,(-1+z)-camz)
  pu()
  goto3d((-1+x)-camx,(1+y)-camy,(-1+z)-camz)
  pd()
  goto3d((-1+x)-camx,(1+y)-camy,(1+z)-camz)
  goto3d((1+x)-camx,(1+y)-camy,(1+z)-camz)
  goto3d((1+x)-camx,(1+y)-camy,(1+z)-camz)
  goto3d((1+x)-camx,(1+y)-camy,(-1+z)-camz)
  pu()
  goto3d((-1+x)-camx,(-1+y)-camy,(-1+z)-camz)
  pd()
  goto3d((-1+x)-camx,(-1+y)-camy,(1+z)-camz)
  goto3d((1+x)-camx,(-1+y)-camy,(1+z)-camz)
  goto3d((1+x)-camx,(-1+y)-camy,(1+z)-camz)
  goto3d((1+x)-camx,(-1+y)-camy,(-1+z)-camz)
  pu()
  goto3d((-1+x)-camx,(1+y)-camy,(1+z)-camz)
  pd()
  goto3d((-1+x)-camx,(-1+y)-camy,(1+z)-camz)
  pu()
  goto3d((1+x)-camx,(1+y)-camy,(1+z)-camz)
  pd()
  goto3d((1+x)-camx,(-1+y)-camy,(1+z)-camz)
def black():
  pencolor('black')
  pu()
  goto(-400,-400)
  pd()
  begin_fill()
  goto(-200,200)
  goto(200,200)
  goto(200,-200)
  end_fill()
def w():
  global camz
  global camx
  camz+=.3*cos(yrot)
  camx+=-1*.3*sin(yrot)
def a():
  global camz
  global camx
  camz+=-1*.3*sin(yrot)
  camx+=-1*.3*cos(yrot)
def s():
  global camz
  global camx
  camz+=-1*.3*cos(yrot)
  camx+=.3*sin(yrot)
def d():
  global camz
  global camx
  camz+=.3*sin(yrot)
  camx+=.3*cos(yrot)
def left():
  global yrot
  yrot+=pi/50
def right():
  global yrot
  yrot-=pi/50
def jump():
  global jvel
  if onground==True:
    jvel=.3
wn.onkey(w,'w')
wn.onkey(a,'a')
wn.onkey(s,'s')
wn.onkey(d,'d')
wn.onkey(left,'Left')
wn.onkey(right,'Right')
wn.onkey(jump,'Space')
wn.listen()
def bush(x,y,z):
  pencolor('darkgreen')
  cube(0+x,0+y,0+z)
  cube(2+x,0+y,0+z)
  cube(2+x,2+y,0+z)
def tree(x,y,z):
  pencolor('brown')
  cube(0+x,0+y,0+z)
  cube(0+x,2+y,0+z)
  pencolor('green')
  cube(0+x,4+y,0+z)
  cube(0+x,6+y,0+z)
  cube(2+x,4+y,0+z)
  cube(-2+x,4+y,0+z)
  cube(0+x,4+y,2+z)
  cube(0+x,4+y,-2+z)
def render():
  bush(-5,0,10)
  tree(3,0,7)
while True:
  clear()
  black()
  render()
  update()
  jvel-=.01
  camy+=jvel
  if camy<=0:
    camy=0
    jvel=.01
    onground=True
  if camy>=.3:
    onground=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not culling out vertices that lie behind the camera. I cannot see any evidence of culling in your code. If you render a point that lies behind the camera, it will appear upside down in the result. You are not actually turning 360 degrees, but 180 degrees. When the voxels are directly behind you, they will appear inverted if you don't cull it. You can test this by printing the `yrot` variable. Try modifying the line `if newx<=-200 or newy<=-200 or newx>=200 or newy>=200` to include a check of `transz`, i.e. `if transz < 0.1 or newx<=-200 or newy<=-200 or newx>=200 or newy>=200`. Any small value will do but `0.1`  should work well in your current implementation.